# Is it possible to set the constraint area on OMNeT++ as a circle instead of a rectangle?

Tags: eclipse, omnet++

I'm trying to define the simulation playground area to be a circle instead of a rectangle/ square on OMNeT++ but I cannot find any variables to use other than constraintAreaMaxX and constraintAreaMaxY, which imply a rectangular shape not a circle

Answer (score 1):

No. But you can implement your own mobility model where you can constrain the movement as you wish.